# Converting XMLList to Array of Strings in as3 error

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, xmllist

I am trying to convert an XMLList into an array of strings in as3 code. Here is the XMLList (lines):

```
<data>
   <conversation id="1" name="blah" key="area1" emptyState="false" background="null" alpha=".1">
    <scene numOfLines = "3">
      <lines>
          <line>This is a test for area1</line>
          <line>Hodor!</line>
          <line>The man who passes the sentence should swing the sword</line>
      </lines>
      <ll>bear</ll>
      <lr>shalev</lr>
      <rl>sarah</rl>
      <rr>taryn</rr>
    </scene>
  </conversation>
</data>
```

And here is the as3 code I use to convert it:

```
for each (var line:String in data.lines.line){
            conversationLine.push(line);
}
```

However the output isnt the text that appears in the xml (e.g. This is a test for area1) it is just the number of the line. So for the above code it would print 0, 1, 2.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: The array conversationLine is declared above like so: private var conversationLine:Array;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you are iterating over are `XML` objects, so you should cast your iterator to `XML`.

Example:

```
for each (var line:XML in data.lines.line){
    conversationLine.push(line.text());
}
```